# Drupal difference between DatabaseQueue and BatchQueue

Tags: drupal

Looking at the [Drupal queue documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.api.php/group/queue/8.2.x) it is not clear what the difference is between a [DatabaseQueue](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Queue%21DatabaseQueue.php/class/DatabaseQueue/8.2.x) and a [BatchQueue](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Queue%21Batch.php/class/Batch/8.2.x)? Are both FIFO? Will they expire? Serial meaning not concurrent processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the source of Batch.php:

```
/**
 * Defines a batch queue handler used by the Batch API.
 *
 * This implementation:
 * - Ensures FIFO ordering.
 * - Allows an item to be repeatedly claimed until it is actually deleted (no
 *   notion of lease time or 'expire' date), to allow multipass operations.
 *
 * Stale items from failed batches are cleaned from the {queue} table on cron
 * using the 'created' date.
 *
 * @ingroup queue
 */
 class Batch extends DatabaseQueue {
```

Batch extends DatabaseQueue. In my experience, `batch` is most often used with a form, as it will automatically process the batch after it's built.

- Yes, FIFO.
- No, items don't expire.
- And yes, serial processing.